# embedded jetty server does not run both servlet and webapp

Tags: jsp, servlets, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am writing a POC for embedded Jetty 9.4.3.x server.  When I run the server with multiple handlers, only the first handler works.  In the code if I have 'context' as the first handler, my hello servlet works and for jsp I get a 404 error.  If I have 'webapp' as the first handler, jsp works and I get a 404 for servlet.  Here is the code.  Am I missing anything?  The servlet and jsp files are simple test files.  If needed I can add the webdefault.xml and jetty.xml files.

```
package com.easyask.server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration;

public class EasyAskServer {
    private static String m_webdefaultXMLFileName = "etc/webdefault.xml";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();

    List<String> configurations = new ArrayList<String>();
    configurations.add("etc/jetty.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    configurations.add("etc/jetty-http.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("etc/jetty-ssl.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("etc/jetty-ssl-context.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("etc/jetty-https.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    XmlConfiguration last = null;
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    try{
        for (String configFile : configurations) {
            InputStream configStream = null;

            File xmlConfiguration = new File(configFile);
            if (xmlConfiguration.exists()) {
                configStream = new FileInputStream(xmlConfiguration);
            }

            XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(configStream);
            if (last != null) {
                configuration.getIdMap().putAll(last.getIdMap());
            }
            objects.add(configuration.configure());
            last = configuration;
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    server = (Server) objects.get(0);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setResourceBase("com/easyask/server");
    context.addServlet(HelloServlet.class, "/hello");

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setResourceBase("com/easyask/server");
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setExtractWAR(false);
    webapp.setDefaultsDescriptor(m_webdefaultXMLFileName);
    webapp.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", "tmp");

    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
            .setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
    classlist.addBefore(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

    webapp.setAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();

    handlers.addHandler(context);
    handlers.addHandler(webapp);
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    try {
        server.start();
        server.dumpStdErr();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have both the `ServletContextHandler` and `WebAppContext` on the same `contextPath`, that's not going to work.

Merge them together.

Either have only a `ServletContextHandler` or a `WebAppContext` on `contextPath("/")`