# Embedded jetty not loading servlet or jersey servlet container.I am able to load either of them but not both

Tags: jersey, embedded-jetty

I am running embedded jetty with jersey container. I am testing if i can head to '/hello' to read my servlet which can request dispatch and another url '/entry/test' to head into my entrypoint class. Only one of them works based on which handler was added at the last.

I have tried to reason out similar to : [embedded jetty server does not run both servlet and webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533423/embedded-jetty-server-does-not-run-both-servlet-and-webapp)

```java
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(
    ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
contextHandler.setContextPath("/*");

Server jettyServer = new Server(8980);

WebAppContext webappcontext = new WebAppContext();
File warPath = new File( System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/main/resources");
webappcontext.setWar(warPath.getAbsolutePath());

webappcontext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed",
    "false");
webappcontext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()), "/hello");


ServletHolder jerseyServlet = contextHandler.addServlet(
     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

jerseyServlet.setInitParameter( "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
     EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

HandlerList handlerCollection = new HandlerList();
//handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandler,webappcontext });
handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] { webappcontext,contextHandler }); 


// Based on which handler was added last, i am able to view /hello or /entry/test

jettyServer.setHandler(handlerCollection);

try {
    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();
} finally {
    jettyServer.destroy();
}
```

/hello to display my servlet page and /entry/test to view entrypoint class content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to mix `WebAppContext` and `ServletContextHandler` in your situation.

Use one or the other.

- Use `WebAppContext` if you have a formal WAR file, with a (optional) `WEB-INF/web.xml`.  Use if you need to have runtime bytecode/annotation scanning of your classes (for things like `@WebServlet`).
- Use `ServletContextHandler` if you are manually declaring Servlets (like you currently are).

Also, do not use the url-pattern `"/*"` in your Jersey configuration, that pretty much means that Jersey will take requests.  Section Jersey off into it's own url-pattern if you can. A common approach is to have `"/api/*"` be handled by Jersey, and the rest be handled by whatever you want to use in the Servlet container.  If you go this approach, make sure you have a solid understanding of how the Servlet spec works with context paths, url patterns, path specs, path infos, etc, as this will help you navigate the Jersey configuration properly.

Example of what you have, but using only `ServletContextHandler`

```java
Server jettyServer = new Server(8980);

ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(
        ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
// Context-paths are not patterns, they are prefixes
contextHandler.setContextPath("/");

// Setup where static files are found
File warPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/main/resources");
Resource warResource = new PathResource(warPath);
contextHandler.setBaseResource(warResource);

// Add your Jersey setup
// BWEE! BWEE! do not use "/*" for your url-pattern, if you want to do things
// in your servlet container that is not Jersey.
String jerseyUrlPattern = "/api/*";
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = contextHandler.addServlet(
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, jerseyUrlPattern);
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
        EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

// Add your custom Servlets
contextHandler.addServlet(MyServlet.class, "/hello");

// Add DefaultServlet to serve static files (servlet spec requirement)
// always added last in your ServletContext.
// always named "default" for this specific servlet setup (per spec)
ServletHolder defaultHolder = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
defaultHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
// always at url-pattern "/" for this specific servlet (per spec)
contextHandler.addServlet(defaultHolder, "/");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(contextHandler);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // used to show config errors

jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);

try
{
    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();
}
finally
{
    jettyServer.stop(); // use STOP not .destroy()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joakim . It worked as expected. Only problem now is requestdispatcher is not forwarding into the html as expected.

Comment: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("And we are in servlet");
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index2.html");
        System.out.println("request Dispatcher = " + requestDispatcher);
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: index2.html is placed in the same path where war path is:   File warPath = new File("D:/Intellij/Projects/JettyJersey/src/main/resources");
        Resource warResource = new PathResource(warPath);
        contextHandler.setBaseResource(warResource);

Comment: Please help me understand this as to why on browser it states:                    HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /index2.html. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: Yes ,, after  a lot of tests and debugging found out that , for some odd reason my resource location is being set at D:\  . But my code is pointed at --> D:/Intellij/Projects/JettyJersey/src/main/resources, hence when i place index.html in D:/ I see the webpage being rendered. Let me post if i reason it out any further.         Code Snip for reference :  File warPath = new File("D:/Intellij/Projects/JettyJersey/src/main/resources");
        Resource warResource = new PathResource(warPath);
contextHandler.setBaseResource(warResource);